# Matching string for patters via MATCH?

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

Is there a function in Business Objects Web Intelligence (Version 2010) to test if a string contains a constant? I know the `MATCH()` function can be used to test a string for a pattern, similar to how SQL implements a LIKE condition.

For example:

```
myString = 'abc,def,ghi'
myString2 = 'def,ghi,jkl'
```

Both string variables above contain the constant 'def', but is there a function to test for this rather than using:

```
=IF(MATCH([Dimension];"def") OR MATCH([Dimension];"*def") 
  OR MATCH([Dimension];"def*") OR MATCH([Dimension];"*def*"))
//Do something
```

I have looked through the functions and formulas manual and haven't found what I was looking for, hence, here I am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MATCH([Dimension];"*def*"))` will produce the result you need.  The wildcard will match the beginning of the string.

Alternatively, you can use **Pos()**:

`=Pos("def abc ghi";"def")`
returns 1

`=Pos("def abc ghi";"abc")`
returns 5

`=Pos("def abc ghi";"xyz")`
returns 0

Comment: I had presumed the wildcard required values and would not return those which started or ended with the pattern provided. Thank you for providing the alternative approach, it was not useful for this particular problem but may well be adopted as a solution in the future.

Comment: Is there a way to match **multiple occurences** of string A in string B? `Match` only return a boolean and `Pos` only returns the index of the first match it finds. Maybe split the string into an iterable array based on a common delimiter and return a count?

Comment: Not directly.  You'd need to use Substr() or Right()  to extract the string after the first occurrence of the search string, then search that.